# AJAX using HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: javascript, ajax

My AJAX request is using HTTP even though the request is originating from a page using HTTPS.  Any idea why it's downgrading to HTTP?

Here's my AJAX request:

```
$(function() {

  // Update section options whne course is changed
  $('#id_new_course').change(function() {

    // Get selected coursenum
    var val = $(this).val();
    var sect_input = $('#id_section');

    // Disable #id_section when no course is selected
    if (val == '') {
      sect_input.empty();
      sect_input.prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      // Get list of sections for selected course and update #id_section options
      $.ajax({
        url: '/account/support_dashboard.get_course_sections/' + val + '/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          // Empty options and add new ones to #id_section
          sect_input.empty();
          $.each(data, function(value, key) {
            sect_input.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', value).text(key));
          });
          sect_input.prop('disabled', false);
        },
        error: function() {
          console.log('ERROR OCCURRED TRY AGAIN');
        }
      });//ajax
    }//if

  });

}); //ready
```

Here's the error output in my web console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.myeducator.com/account/support_dashboard/1027/993532704604577793/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.myeducator.com/account/support_dashboard.get_course_sections/915ba/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

The javascript file is being loaded over HTTPS:

[image: Request Over HTTPS]

Also, the actual ajax request is going out as HTTPS:

[image: AJAX Request over HTTPS]

I also don't think it has anything to do with my web server (nginx).  I only have a single rewrite command that redirects any unhandled subdomains to www.myeducator.com using the same request scheme:

```
server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  server_name _;

  ...

  # the rewrite string
  rewrite ^ $scheme://www.myeducator.com$request_uri redirect;
}
```

Comment: And is the .js file loaded from https ?

Comment: When you look at the http request in the console. do you see it making a https call?

Comment: Interesting question.  I wonder why jQuery is not picking up the https from source page when you pass it a domain relative URL?  As a work-around, I guess you could grab the protocol, port and domain from `window.location` and add that to your URL.

Comment: If thise is really the code that is running, then this must either be caused by either (1) an explicit downgrade by the server (i.e., the client does request HTTPS, but the server responds with a redirect to HTTP) or else (2) there's some kind of `jQuery.ajaxPrefilter` modification going on elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @adeneo  see my edit above.  It is being served over HTTPS

Comment: @apsillers see my edit above about my nginx config.  Also, nowhere in my code base is there a reference to .ajaxPrefilter besides in the jQuery file where it's set up initially.

Answer (score -1):

The real reason is probably you are not forwarding the proxy ssl connection.